# Cannot make my program executable when using Ecplipse export

Tags: java, file, jar, makefile, executable

Dear fellow java enthusiast,

I would like to make my java program into a executable .jar file with the help of eclipse. I exported into a .jar file but when I double click it it does not seem to work? I think i am missing something but after some time trying to find how to do it i cant find it.

Any advice?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GravityMoon {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your earthweight in kilograms below:");

    Scanner earthweight = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Repeat until next item is a double
    while (!earthweight.hasNextDouble()) 
    {        
        // Read and discard offending non-double input
        earthweight.next(); 
        // Re-prompt
        System.out.print("Please enter your earthweight "
                + "in numerical kilograms: "); 
    }

    double moonweight;

    // Converts earthweight in moonweight 17%
    moonweight = earthweight.nextDouble() * 0.17; 

    // convert to whole numbers


    //closes keyboard input
    earthweight.close(); 

    //prints out your moonweight in a decimal number
    System.out.println("Your moonweight is " + Math.round(moonweight * 100d) /100d 
            + " kilograms.");

        }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you did not explain the exact problem, I might only give hints:

1. Export as Executable Jar

   In Eclipse, there is the option to export into a jar file and another option to export into an executable jar file (see http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm).
2. (I guess you are using windows) Try to execute the jar file from the console (something like java -jar ).

   Double klicking a jar file in windows does not open a terminal window.